# SQLite and Python are inserting unwanted linebreaks into database

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I'm writing a little program that inserts and retrieves movie information in a database. If I type the info into the .db file manually, the program retrieves it and displays it perfectly in my GUI's textboxes. However, if I try to insert data from those textboxes into my database, it adds a linebreak to the end of each field. When I retrieve it again, it has "\n" at the end. The retrieving works great, but somehow linebreaks are being included in my inserts. Here is my insert function:

```
def addRecord(self):
    newTitle = self.text_title.get(1.0, 'end')
    newSynopsis = self.text_summary.get(1.0, 'end')
    newCast = self.text_cast.get(1.0, 'end')
    newRuntime = self.text_runtime.get(1.0, 'end')
    newRating = self.text_rating.get(1.0, 'end')
    newTrailer = self.text_trailer.get(1.0, 'end')
    newDates = self.text_date2d.get(1.0, 'end')
    newImage = self.text_image.get(1.0, 'end')

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Synopsis, Actors, Runtime, Rating, Trailer, Dates, Image) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');"
              .format(newTitle, newSynopsis, newCast, newRuntime, newRating, newTrailer, newDates, newImage))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I decided to add [:-1] to the end of each "newBlah" variable to cut the linebreaks off before the information is inserted into the database. That fixed it, but I still don't know why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter automatically adds a newline as the last character in the text widget. The proper way to get only the contents of the text widget that you or the user inserted you should use `"end-1c"` ("end" minus one character) rather than `"end"` or `END`.

Also, to be pedantic, the first index should be a string, not a float. In the case of `1.0` it doesn't matter, but you should be in the habit of always using strings for the indexes in a text widget.

For example:

```
newTitle = self.text_title.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
```

Comment: Excellent, that solves it. Thanks for the explanation!